# What Should This Phenomenon Be Called?

Tags: science-based, physics, light

I've been searching for over a week now, and I haven't found anything to describe the following:

A floating spherical area of space that reflects light over a gradient. This is exclusively [specular reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection).

By "over a gradient", I mean that light is reflected more strongly the closer it gets to the center of the sphere.

You can consider this to be like an anti-[gravitational lensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens) situation.

The closest thing I've found to this is a [white hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hole), which is not what I want. The only light that should be coming from the spherical region is light that has entered it from the outside and then reflected.

## Does this phenomenon have a name?

[Negative mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) seems to be related, but I'm having trouble finding enough info on it to decide if that's really what I'm looking for.
I have found [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263659549_Negative_gravitational_lensing_effect_Confinement_by_surrounding_negative_matter) regarding negative mass and positive mass interactions, but I am struggling to understand it.

---

I'm also struggling with how the phenomenon would appear to an observer, assuming there are plenty of objects surrounding the spherical region for it to be visible.

---

> I originally wrote this question for Physics.SE. I also looked at Astronomy.SE just in case. But those communities do not appear to have [negative-mass](/questions/tagged/negative-mass) or [negative-matter](/questions/tagged/negative-matter) tags, and since I'm asking this question because of my story, I decide to ask it here. **If this was a mistake, please help me move it to the appropriate community.**

---

EDIT: I suppose the closest thing to what I'm looking for is a black hole of negative mass. That is, light gets bent outwards away from the center. It would bend slightly at the edges, but if a photon were to travel directly into this phenomenon's center, the photon slows down until it at some point stops and changes direction, then moving away.

There would even be an event horizon, which cannot be crossed or entered even by light.

Comment: [Cat's eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat's_eye_(road)) seems to fit somewhat, else I'm missing your meaning. Are you asking for the **name** for such a (in the case you describe) spherical occurrence of this phenomenon?

Comment: 1. StackExchange is not a Forum, but a Q&A network. 2. You likely won't much conclusive writing on negative mass, because it's a highly theoretical subject....

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Fixed.

Comment: What does "reflected more strongly the closest you get" mean? A single light packet does not carry information about the distance of the source, it would be reflected or not wherever it came from. If you refer to the angle of incidence, you might be referring to a negative refraction index. I am *not* sure, but the weird effect you describe *could* be what is called a *Veselago mirror*.

Comment: Do you mean that light incident on this object (phenomenon) would be evenly re-emitted  in each and every direction - but only in such a way as the incident light could be observed only on a direct axis to the object/phenomenon's center? Or are you asking something different? I'm not certain what you're asking, if you can't provide direct reference to such a phenomenon, this all seems a matter of opinion. 'Till then I'm voting to close as unclear what you are asking. (Also, not sure what this has to do with any world you are building).

Comment: @011358smell He specifies "specular reflection".  His link should adequately answer your question.

Comment: @Nosajimiki I shouldn't think so, gravitational lensing (or as the OP puts it "Anti gravitational lensing") would be to do with light incident from behind the object as viewed by the observer. Should we take Anti to mean in this case, just specular reflection or is the OP wanting to indicate a phenomenon which acts as a bi-concave lens around it's periphery, yet any light directly incident upon it should only emerge on-axis with the phenomenon's center? Since the OP has not clarified, it appears that neither of us is qualified to determine what the correct interpretation is. Cont..

Comment: Care to ping the OP for clarification? I did without result.

Comment: I suppose the closest thing to what I'm looking for is a black hole of negative mass. That is, light gets bent outwards away from the center. It would bend slightly at the edges, but if a photon were to travel directly into this phenomenon's center, the photon slows down until it at some point stops and changes direction, then moving away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is region of **negative space-time curvature**.

Positive space-time curvature, like that caused by a black hole, a star, or even a planet, causes light to bend inward towards the source of gravity.

The opposite, where light is deflected away from the "source" (regardless of what it might be) is effectively negative space-time curvature.

I'm not sure what could cause such a phenomenon (exotic/negative mass does indeed come to mind), but it should be noted that if you want it to behave consistently with relativistic physics, it would probably not only reflect light but also "accelerate" time for nearby objects compared to distant objects and "repel" mass gravitationally -- so that if you make it strong enough, it might indeed behave like the opposite of a black hole.

> I'm also struggling with how the phenomenon would appear to an
>   observer, assuming there are plenty of objects surrounding the
>   spherical region for it to be visible.

It would appear as a mirror at the middle, reflecting objects around you as a tiny, tiny image. However, it would have no defined edge...reflected images would get bigger as you look away from the center until they merge with the objects of which they are reflections.

Also, technically, everything you see in your whole field of vision would be pushed very slightly "inward", towards the source, compared to the "true direction" you would see without the negative space-time curvature.

---

**To further help you envision it**, check out this video of a simulated wormhole:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZDOKtT_QZE

Your orb of light-deflection will have a similar look to it, except without the "tunnel" part in the middle--there you will only see a reflection of yourself and objects behind/around you.

Comment: Interesting. This spherical region of negative spacetime would be about the size of a basketball and would float around like an individual sentient being.

Comment: Note that you can have regions of negative space curvature without exotic negative matter. The region between two positive mass objects can have negative curvature for suitable masses and distances of the two objects.

Comment: Good point! I suppose, despite the extra verbosity, I should have called it an "acute region of particularly strong negative space-time curvature" xD

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for!

Comment: Hooray! Glad this works :)

Answer (score 3):

### Maybe a Reflection Nebula

I don't think that there is a common name for the property of having a reflection gradient, in space. This scenario probably isn't prevalent enough to require a term for it. However there might be a common name for some other cosmic phenomena, that has reflection gradient potential.

For example if you are creating this reflection gradient by having a region of space filled with tiny reflective dust particles (nebula), whose density increases the closer you are to center of the dust cloud (perhaps because of gravity). Then what you are describing would be similar to a [reflection nebula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_nebula). However with much, much, more [reflectance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflectance) than what is normally seen in the universe.

This would give you a reflection gradient, especially if there is star formation at the center of the nebula to really increase the density of these particles the closer you get to the center. But this situation would not create a solid reflection like what you might see in a mirror. So if that is what you are looking for, then you might be looking for something else.

Comment: I'm not looking for a solid reflection. There should be no easily observable boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

### Rendering software simply calls this "Gradient Transparency"

... and what you are describing is not nearly as exotic as you may think. Translucence is a property of nearly all matter whereby it reflects some of the light that hits it, ands allows some to pass through.  If you create a mass of translucent material it does not just reflect N-% of light, it reflects a little bit of light for each molecule it passes through.  This means you have a greater level of reflection when looking at the thicker core of a translucent sphere than at the edges.  Rendering methods that simulate this 3d effect in 2d use "Gradient Transparency".

> I'm also struggling with how the phenomenon would appear to an
>   observer, assuming there are plenty of objects surrounding the
>   spherical region for it to be visible.

For starters, it will not look like a mirror because the light will not stay together as is does when bouncing off of an opaque surface:

[image: Reflective vs Translucent Orbs]

Depending on how homogeneous the medium is, it will cause a combination of Refraction and Diffusion, but the general mechanic is the same either way.  As the light passes through the medium, part of it will keep going straight and part will reflect.  If the medium is homogeneous, then the reflected light will mostly refract creating the illusion of bending the light as seen in the first figure below.  If the medium is heterogeneous, then the scattering will be more random creating more diffusion.  You will not see any shapes reflected in it, but you will still see more light through the edges than through the core.  Highly diffusive mediums appear to almost glow in a color that is the average color of its environment.

[image: Refractive vs Diffusive Orbs]

But you are asking about an area of space that does this at a gradient, not a continuous medium.  Lucky for you, this exact anomaly can been seen right here in our own solar system.  We call them gas giants.  Gravity and air pressure create a gradient of translucent gases whereby you get the exact effect you describe... unfortunately, they are so big that it's really hard to see how the thin upper atmosphere transitions into the thicker more opaque core.

[image]

That said, nothing says gas giants HAVE to be giant, they could just as easily be quite small and mostly see through.  If you were to find a really small gas planet, it would probably look like you are describing.

**What if you specifically want to do it with anti-gravity?**

At this point you are working with theoretical forces that are and not actually specular reflection, but this effect is called [Negative Weak Gravitational Lensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_gravitational_lensing).